# How to find which process leads to DailyLimitExceeded on a Google Analytics profileID?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

Since last two days I am receiving a dailyLimitExceeded error on one of the Profiles that I run queries on - even if I run it early in the day. I understand happens when there are more than 10000 queries for the same profile in the day. As far as we have researched internally, no known process from our company is sending such a large number of queries for this profile via APIs. Is there a way to find out what is causing this problem? 
ProfileID = ga:64708881
Is it possible to find out the source of queries for this profile that is leading to dailyLimitExceeded error?

Comment: Are you sure its not the project limit? That is 50k check developer console see if you have hit that limit.  Both profile limit and the main project limit will give the dailyLimitExceeded error.

Comment: I checked the Developer Console limit as well.That was the first checkpoint. Its way below the limit.